# adding elements in a two dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to add uniqueArray elements to first column and counter array to second column of finalArray
How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Also, say specifically where you're stuck doing what you want to do.

Comment: JAVA != JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a mapping from value to how many times it was encountered? Take a look at the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). With the Map your problem can be solved like that:

```
    int[] arr = new int[] {1, 1, 1, 2, 3};
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(arr.length);
    for (int val : arr) {
        map.compute(val, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

But don't use this approach if you have many values (more than 10000 or so) because autoboxing.